# How to reduce the text size for PDF and Print in table tools : HTML

Tags: javascript, pdf, printing, datatables, tabletools

I am using Table tools to generate the PDF,CSV,EXCEL,and Print as

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="../mymedia/savefiles/TableTools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready( function () {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "oTableTools": {
        "sScrollY": 200,
        "sScrollX": "100%",
        "sScrollXInner": "110%",
        "sSwfPath": "../mymedia/savefiles/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"

    }
    } )
    .columnFilter({
        aoColumns: {{columnfilters|safe}}

    });
    } );
</script>
```

In my table having more number of fields nearly 10 to 15 when I generate PDF with this table it is splitting the word and displaying for print it is previewing only some fields(around 5 fields not all),how can i reduce the text size to fit all fields and text in PDF without spiting text words and for PRINT to fit in A4 sheet,Please help me out

Comment: Some one please help me

Comment: PSSR, have replaced the datatable tag with the jquery-datatables tag.  Guess thats why your question not achieved more attention.